# Removing for loop somehow? and changing the way my reading of difference is?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, comparator, indexof

So to begin with I am basically playing the Price is right...With a public getWinner() to calculate if the guess was under the item price I have listed how I get it but my teacher does not like for loops so I am attempting to changed this and also fix my int difference variable so it does not look messy.

```
@Override
public Contestant getWinner() {
    int difference = 999999999;
        Contestant winner = null;

    for (Contestant person: allContestants){
        int personDifference= anItem.getPrice() - person.getAmount();
        if (personDifference >= 0 && personDifference < difference){
            winner= person;
            difference = personDifference;
        }
    }
    if (difference < 0) {
            return null;
        }
    return winner; 
}
```

For extra info I have this as my GuessOnItem class which extends my abstract

```
public GuessOnItem (ItemOnDisplay inItem){
    anItem= inItem;
    allContestants = new ArrayList<Contestant>();
    }

public GuessOnItem (ItemOnDisplay inItem, List<Contestant> contestantList){
    anItem= inItem;
    allContestants= contestantList;
}
```

I have a contestant class that has the constructor that compares the  byName already. Just cleaning it up is what I am struggling with. Thank for the help.

Comment: Your teacher "does not like `for` loops"? Is there more specific criticism, or is your teacher just insane?

Comment: You my want to use constant like `Integer.MAX_VALUE` for your initial difference value.

Comment: Ok I will try the integer part and he does not like for loops with if statements in it.

Comment: The Max value worked perfect just need to reiterate that for loop somehow thank Mr. Yetti for cleaning up that